# How to fire a textbox command upon losing focus in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The following template works fine if the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, although I want the command to fire when the `TextBox` loses focus as well. How can I do this?

The following is my `TextBox` template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PhantomNameEditTemplate">          
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <TextBox.InputBindings>                 
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.RenameCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Key="Enter" />
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
    </TextBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't use any MVVM framework you could use `InvokeCommandAction` from  [`System.Windows.Interactivity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity(v=expression.40).aspx) to execute command when event is fired

```
<TextBox ...>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.RenameCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

you'll need to add reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity` and add namespace in your XAML:

> xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

Comment: Thank you, I am not using a MVVM framework and that worked perfectly.

Comment: With .NET >5 the namespace import has changed to: `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"`

Comment: 2022, WPF Interactivity is now a Nuget package: `Microsoft.XAML.Behaviors`, and the XAML reference is now `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"`