# Reload data when page is back in focurs

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls

I am pretty new in the c# / xaml / usercontrol things so i hope you understand my question.

Our tutor prohibits us from using code behind but i don't see a solution to my problem without it.

Problem:
I have several usercontrols where i edit info threw a combination of dropboxes and normal fields. Threw viewmodels (example added below). But when i change to a diffrent page (usecontrol) the info stays inputed and edited in the models.

What i am looking for without any luck is a way to reset the data in the back when a usercontrol is loaded in again.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyDevices.wpf.UserControls.GroepUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyDevices.wpf.UserControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         DataContext="{Binding GroepVm, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.8*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.8*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Groep"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="GroepSelected"
              Grid.Row="1" 
              Grid.Column="2"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Groepen, Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroep, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"    
              Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
              IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=NewGroepCheckbox, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToEnabledConverter}}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Naam}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
    <!-- Nieuwe Groep -->
    <CheckBox x:Name="NewGroepCheckbox"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="6"
              Content = "Nieuwe Groep"
              IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckBoxChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
              Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle}"/>
    <!-- Naam -->
    <Label Content="Naam"
           Grid.Row="3"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="AppNaam"
             Text="{Binding SelectedGroep.Naam, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Grid.Row="3"
             Grid.Column="2"
             Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
    <!-- Uitleg -->
    <Label Content="Uitleg"
           Grid.Row="5"
           Grid.Column="0"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="AppUitleg"
             Text="{Binding SelectedGroep.Uitleg, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Grid.Row="5"
             Grid.Column="2"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
             AcceptsReturn="True"
             Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"/>
    <!-- Cancel button -->
    <Button x:Name="AppCancel"
            Content="Cancel"
            Grid.Row="7"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
            Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
    <!-- Save button -->
    <Button x:Name="AppSave"
            Content="Save"
            Grid.Row="7"
            Grid.Column="6"
            Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
            Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

```
using System;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
using MyDevices.Domain.Models;
using MyDevices.Domain.Helpers;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using MyDevices.Domain.DataServices;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyDevices.Domain.ViewModels
{
public class GroepViewModel : ViewModelBase, IPage, IDataOperations
{
    private IDataService _dataService = null;
    //private ObservableCollection<ApparaatModel> _apparaten;
    private ObservableCollection<GroepModel> _groepen;
    private GroepModel _selectedGroepModel;
    private GroepModel _newGroep;
    private bool _isCheckBoxChecked;

    public string PageName => "Groep";

    public GroepModel NewGroep
    {
        get => _newGroep ?? (_newGroep = new GroepModel());
        set

        {
            if (_newGroep == value)
                return;

            _newGroep = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Geef de lijst terug van alle apparaten in de groep
    /// </summary>
    //public ObservableCollection<ApparaatModel> Apparaten
    //{
    //    get => _apparaten ?? (_apparaten = new ObservableCollection<ApparaatModel>());
    //}

    /// <summary>
    /// Welk groep hebben we geselecteerd
    /// </summary>
    public GroepModel SelectedGroep
    {
        get => _selectedGroepModel ?? (_selectedGroepModel = new GroepModel());
        set
        {
            if (_selectedGroepModel == value)
                return;

            _selectedGroepModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedGroep);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<GroepModel> Groepen
    {
        get => _groepen ?? (_groepen = new ObservableCollection<GroepModel>());
        set
        {
            if (_groepen == value)
                return;

            _groepen = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private async void GetGroepen()
    {
        Groepen = new ObservableCollection<GroepModel>(await _dataService.GetGroepen());
    }

    public bool IsCheckBoxChecked
    {
        get => _isCheckBoxChecked;
        set
        {
            if (_isCheckBoxChecked == value)
                return;

            _isCheckBoxChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // Commands
    public ICommand CancelCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() => SelectedGroep = new GroepModel());
        }
    }

    public ICommand SaveCommand => new RelayCommand(Save);

    // Constructor
    public GroepViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        _selectedGroepModel = new GroepModel();
        GetGroepen();
        //_apparaten = new List<ApparaatModel>();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        if (SelectedGroep.GroepId != null)
        {
            NewGroep = SelectedGroep;
            if (IsCheckBoxChecked)
            {
                NewGroep.GroepId = new Guid();
            }
            _dataService.AddGroep(NewGroep);
            NewGroep = new GroepModel();
            GetGroepen();
        }
    }

    public void Reload()
    {
        GetGroepen();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It seems that you are allowed to use commands and code in your viewmodel, so why not create a command for the `onFocus` event and handle it in your viewmodel? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018519/how-to-fire-a-textbox-command-upon-losing-focus-in-wpf) might point you in the right direction.

Comment: I tried something similar as what you are sugesting. When i implement this i get following error. xxx is not a method.

I want all the data to be reset as soon as the page comes back into focus (but a usercontrol can not be onfocus)

Comment: In your case, is it possible to use the onFocus of the container/parent of the usercontrol?

Comment: Ah that would not realy be possible. As the usercontrol is loaded into the window. Meaning the window stays in focus all the time.

Comment: Will there be more UserControls in the same window? Because if you only load one UserControl at a time, you could try hooking it to the `Loaded`-Event. **EDIT** I just checked, `UserControl` does have the `OnFocused`-Event

Comment: Errors i get "The member "OnFocused" is not recognized or is not accesible.
The property 'OnFocused' was not found in type 'UserControl'.

When i add a binding on Loaded i get 'OnFocusCommand' is not a method.

(this is the OnFocusCommand i used)
    // Reload de data.
        public ICommand OnFocusCommand => new RelayCommand(Reload);

    // Reload al de data.
        public void Reload()
        {
            GetApparaten();
            GetGroepen();
            GetWinkels();
        }